# R web interface suggestion

Tags: r

hi i was looking for a sophisticated web based interface of R which can be used for couple of analytics application? any suggestion please..rweb is quite simple

Answer (score 1):

Try using R-fiddle:

http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/

They even have several of the most used packages pre-installed.

I think that is something you are looking for. If not, could you describe more thoroughly what you are looking for?